# Google Charts Custom Font Not Rendering Correctly - Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, fonts, google-visualization

We're using Google Charts to create some visualizations on our website. Our site uses a "custom" font called "Gotham A".  The font loads and works fine on the website, body text and all else render just fine and dandy.

For our charts, our X Axis, Y Axis and Titles all use the Gotham A font as well.  In IE and Chrome the charts\title render the font just fine, but FireFox doesn't know how to render it properly.

Below are examples on how they're rendering and the script we have in place to load our charts.  Are there any settings, etc. that I can alter that would help to get these fonts to render properly in FireFox?

Here's a screenshot of the charts in Chrome:
[image]

And here's a cap of the same stuff in FireFox:
[image]

Take a look at "Contract Sales - Past 12 Months", in the Firefox version some of the letters like the lower r, lower s, and the numbers 1 and 2 aren't rendering accurately.  Neither are any of the characters in the axes.

Here's how we're setting the fonts and stuff for the charts:

```
function LoadChart(responseData, chartTitle, xType, xTitle, yType, yTitle, chartDOMObjSelector, chartTitleWidth) {
  var chartFont = 'Gotham A';
  // Set chart options
  var options = {
      'title': chartTitle,
      'width': chartTitleWidth,
      'titleTextStyle': { color: '#606060', fontName: chartFont, fontSize: '14', bold: false, italic: false },
      'hAxis': { textStyle: { color: '#24597f', fontName: chartFont, fontSize: '10', bold: false, italic: false } },
      'vAxis': { textStyle: { color: '#24597f', fontName: chartFont, fontSize: '10', bold: false, italic: false } },
      'legend': { position: 'none' } // set Legend Position to None to hide it
  };

  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  //logic to add row data...
     var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart($('#mychart'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

Comment: when i use one of [google's fonts](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Gloria+Hallelujah?selection.family=Gloria+Hallelujah), it works fine in all three browsers -- have you checked the Network tab in the developer tools to ensure the font is being downloaded?

Comment: Thanks @WhiteHat !  yep, its downloaded.  In those screenshots where you see the terms "Data as of May 26, 2017" and "6 Month Average" - those are in the Gotham font that we're using.  It's only the Google Charts that seem to not be able to interpret the font, and the Console\Network tabs in dev tools don't show any errors whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

not sure if this will help,
but you could make sure all the elements have the correct `font-family`

when the `'ready'` event fires...

```
var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart($('#mychart')[0]);

google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
  $('text').attr('font-family', chartFont);
});

chart.draw(data, options);
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. It's related to a font having a space in the name. I was using Bauhaus 93 and it wasn't working. But when I changed it to include single quotes in the name, 'Bauhaus 93' then it started working for me.